# gdb --args with --symbols

Tags: command-line, gdb

I would like to start `gdb` from the command line, giving it a symbol file via `--symbols` and giving it an executable via `--args`:

```
gdb --symbols=/path/to/symbol_file --args /other_path/to/exe arg1 arg2
```

The problem is that the `--args` flag must come at the end of the `gdb` command, since everything following the executable is passed as an argument to the executable. Since, according to the [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html#File-Options), the executable is treated as both the symbol file and executable file (and the core file), it overwrites the symbol file specified by `--symbols`. This is fixed by doing this instead:

```
gdb --symbols=/path/to/symbol_file --exec=/other_path/to/exe
```

Now, however, I can't pass the inferior arguments to the executable. I know it is possible to provide either the symbol file or the inferior arguments after `gdb` has started using `symbol-file` or `set args`, but is there any way to achieve this all with command line arguments?

GNU gdb (GDB) 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
gdb -q --symbols=/bin/date --exec=/bin/sleep -ex 'set args 60'

Reading symbols from /bin/date...

(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/sleep 60
```

That said, you are *probably* doing it wrong. See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) for how to *automatically* associate the `/path/to/symbol_file` with the binary.